# How to get label associated with checkbox in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

> How can I  print label associated with `<input type="checkbox" />`, like `checkbox 1` or 
>   `checkbox 2` in example below.

Checkbox Items:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="cb1" name="checkboxes[]">Checkbox 1 
<input type="checkbox" value="cb2" name="checkboxes[]">Checkbox 2 
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="cb3" name="checkboxes[]">Checkbox 3
```

I am using below code to get the label name , but it doesn't work.
`getText()` is also not working.

```
List<WebElement>  elementList = driver.findElements(By.name("checkboxes[]"));

System.out.println("checkbox1?  "+elementList.get(0).getAttribute("innerHTML"));`
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML input tags are void elements & they do not need a closing tag and they are not designed for holding any text / other elements inside.  **[Refernce](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-elements)** .

So, getText() / getAttribute("innerHTML") on the 'input' tag element will not work. Find the parent element of the input tag, then find the innerText/innerHTML and parse it to get the text you want!.